# CSS Styling is not changing style / throwing error

Tags: html, css, web

I'm very new to website designing an am trying to change the background colour of a button, but for some reason it's not working. Could someone please help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widthz=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="application.js"></script>
    <h3>Small Header</h3>
    <button id="InformationButton">Information</button>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```css
.InformationButton {
    background-color: aqua;
    border : solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used id to refer the button in your HTML, you should be using the `id selector (#)` instead of the `class selector(.)`.

Thus replace your CSS as below.

```
#InformationButton {
    background-color: aqua;
    border : solid;
}
```

Read more about CSS selectors in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a CSS ID selector to refer to your button. Either change the CSS to a class selector :

```
#InformationButton {
    background-color: aqua;
    border : solid;
}
```

or change your button element to

```
<button class="InformationButton">Information</button>
```